# C Multiply symbol error when adding non-inlined function

Tags: c, compiler-errors, linker

AFAIK multiply symbols occurs when you add a symbol (e.g. a variable declaration in a header) and the header is used multiple times in a single file. This will cause symbol redefinition? or something to go wrong with the linker.

In anycase, I have a global function which uses uses global data (which is declared extern in the .h file). When this function is not __FORCE_INLINE'd then I receive a L6200E: Symbol multiply defined error.

What is the cause of this and why does my global function need to be inlined?

Comment: The cause is presumably that each file that includes your header gets a copy of the function, so you can't have more than of those object files linked into your executable.

Comment: oh I see I thought it was because I was using global data. that makes sense though.